# Using subqueries in delete query

Tags: delete, mysql-5.1, duplication

I have a table `candidate`. It contains two columns `name` and `roll`. The values in all three rows of data are `AA` and `10`. Now I want to delete only the second row. How can I do it?

Say we have an invoice number which automatically updates, but for some reason it has not updated and continued to register the same number again. In such case if I wish to delete the second row, what should I do?

I used this query:

```
delete from candidate where (SELECT * FROM candidate limit 1,1);
```

...but it throws an error saying

> operand should contain one column

Comment: Why doesn't the table have a primary key?

Comment: "Now I want to delete only the second row." The second row, **according to what order**?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this ll give you what u r looking for.

```
  
with rnCTE AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
  FROM candidate
)
DELETE
FROM rnCTE
WHERE rn = 2
```

Or

```
DELETE  rw
FROM    (
        SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
        FROM  candidate
        ) AS rw
WHERE   rw.rn = 2
```

For My Sql

```
delete from candidate
where name = 'AA' and roll= '10'
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where (SELECT * FROM candidate limit 1,1)
```

..is wrong. You need to use:

```
where some_column IN (select other_column ...)
```

But don't do that with MySQL. MySQL is horribly bad at using sub-queries. Use a join instead. - [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)